# Пожалуйста, помогите с запятыми

Tags: пунктуация

Нужны ли здесь запятые?

Но, когда используешь аппарат для его измерения, он показывает, что всё нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Для присоединительного союза НО возможны оба варианта (авторский выбор зависит от контекста, семантики, структуры, распространенности предложения):

(1) Но когда используешь аппарат для его измерения, он показывает, что всё нормально.

(2) Но, когда используешь аппарат для его измерения, он показывает, что всё нормально.

Обычно нет необходимости  в постановке запятой после  присоединительных союзов И, А, НО перед подчинительными союзами , так как в этом случае придаточная часть приобретает вставочный характер (это  надо учитывать при авторском обособлении союза).

Answer (score 0):

Да, всё правильно.
Первая и вторая нужны для выделения придаточного времени, третья - для выделения придаточного изъяснительного.

Answer (score 0):

Например:
*Чувствую, как поднимается давление, но когда используешь аппарат для его измерения, он показывает, что всё нормально.*

Запятая не ставится, поскольку изъятие придаточного предложения невозможно.